# Allow user select from table in another user's schema that has policies set

Tags: oracle, schema, permissions

I have an oracle10g database with 2 users - user A and user B. I want to select data from a table in user A's schema from user B. I have granted user B select privileges on the table in question but I've realized that there is a policy set on the table.

I'm looking for an alternative to granting the "*exempt access policy*" to user B.